# Fetching month and year from timestamps in R in a specific format and ordering them

Tags: r, dplyr, timestamp, plyr, posixct

The script arranges the patients3 data (attached in the package "bupaR" by the name patients) by the column patient and calculates the difference in corresponding timestamps in the time column, then the difference is displayed in seconds, minutes and hours in the last three columns of the data.

My requirement is to create a column in the third last position of the dataset fetching the month and year from the time column in the format "May-2015". E.g. for timestamp "2017-01-02 12:40:20" I need the corresponding new column value to be "January-2017", similarly for others. Also, if the data then can be arranged in ascending order from "January-YYYY" to "December-YYYY" format.

```
library(bupaR)
library(dplyr)
#Declare and assign the variables
patients1 <- arrange(patients, patient)
patients2 <- patients1 %>% arrange(patient, time)
patients3 <- patients2 %>%
group_by(patient) %>%
mutate(diff_in_sec = as.POSIXct(time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") - 
lag(as.POSIXct(time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), 
default=first(as.POSIXct(time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))))%>%
mutate(diff_in_hours = as.numeric(diff_in_sec/3600)) %>% mutate(diff_in_days 
= as.numeric(diff_in_hours/24))
```

Answer (score 0):

OP can append `dplyr` chain to get the desired output. The approach is:

1.Add column `monthyear` using `format` as `"%B-%Y"` (i.e. May-2017)

2.Add column `monthyearNum` using `%m%Y` (`052017`) format. Use this column to sort. Then finally exclude it from `select`

```
mutate(monthyear = format(time, format = "%B-%Y")) %%>
mutate(monthyearNum = as.numeric(time, format = "%m%Y"))) %>%
arrange(monthyearNum) %>%
select(-monthyearNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```r
library(bupaR)
library(dplyr)

patients %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  arrange(patient, time) %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  mutate(diff_in_sec = difftime(time, lag(time, default=first(time)), units="secs"),
         diff_in_min = difftime(time, lag(time, default=first(time)), units="mins"),
         diff_in_hour = difftime(time, lag(time, default=first(time)), units="hours"),
         diff_in_days = difftime(time, lag(time, default=first(time)), units="days"),
         month_year = format(time, "%B-%Y")) %>%
  #ungroup() %>%
  #arrange(time)  #this will sort your data on month_year column
```

**Edit**: updated code to replace NA with 0

Comment: Thanks, I ran your code, however my requirement is a little different here, all I need your help in is to take time column from my script above and fetch Month and Year and display in a new column, the time difference calculation from your code contains 'NA'. Please help.

Comment: See the updated answer. Simply uncomment last line if you want to sort your data on month_year column.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(bupaR)

patients %>% 
  mutate(mon.yr = paste0(month(time, label = T), "-", year(time))) %>% 
  arrange(time)
```

Output:

```
#Event log consisting of:
#5442 events
#7 traces
#500 cases
#7 activities
#2721 activity instances 
#
## A tibble: 5,442 x 8
#   handling              patient employee handling_id registration_type time                .order mon.yr  
#   <fct>                 <chr>   <fct>    <chr>       <fct>             <dttm>               <int> <chr>   
# 1 Registration          1       r1       1           start             2017-01-02 11:41:53      1 Jan-2017
# 2 Registration          2       r1       2           start             2017-01-02 11:41:53      2 Jan-2017
# 3 Triage and Assessment 1       r2       501         start             2017-01-02 12:40:20    501 Jan-2017
# 4 Registration          1       r1       1           complete          2017-01-02 12:40:20   2722 Jan-2017
# 5 Registration          2       r1       2           complete          2017-01-02 15:16:38   2723 Jan-2017
# 6 Triage and Assessment 2       r2       502         start             2017-01-02 22:32:25    502 Jan-2017
# 7 Triage and Assessment 1       r2       501         complete          2017-01-02 22:32:25   3222 Jan-2017
# 8 Triage and Assessment 2       r2       502         complete          2017-01-03 12:34:01   3223 Jan-2017
# 9 Registration          4       r1       4           start             2017-01-04 01:34:04      4 Jan-2017
#10 Registration          3       r1       3           start             2017-01-04 01:34:05      3 Jan-2017
```